# Web page losing information when re-visited via back button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a small responsive webapp (I am new to javascript etc.) I am encountering several strange (to me) problems when the user navigates back to a previous page using the back button. The following outlines my project and the issues.

I have a back end database holding customers and orders. This is interrogated/updated using PHP and SQL and is working as expected.

When the app starts it first downloads all existing customers from the database and populates an array and (html) customer table with the entries.

The user can select/edit an existing customer (via the customer table) or add a new one - which is written to the database then appended to the customers array and table.

Having selected a customer the user can choose to add an order for that customer - which opens the Order page in the current window.

Here I start encountering several issues:

If the user navigates back (using the back button), the customer page is re-displayed but any newly added customers are no longer visible and are not stored in the customers array. A refresh of the page correctly restores all information.

I don't understand why this is the case, any light you may be able to shed this would be much appreciated. I have searched for solutions, but can't seem to find a suitable one (maybe I'm asking the wrong question.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the browser is caching the response from the first page visit. you may be able to change that behavior via appropriate server configuration

Comment: Thanks @StephenThomas